# How to handle manipulators in my overloading <<?

Tags: c++, io

I have class

```
class MyClass {
public:
....
    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const MyClass& myobject);
};

ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const MyClass& myobject){}
```

where I can use manipulators like setprecision

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

MyClass a;
cout << setprecision(9) << a << endl;
```

How I can handle manipulators in my overloading method?
For example, MyClass is wrapper for mpf_t of GMP big number.

```
MyClass a("1.23456789");
```

If I type

```
cout << setprecision(8) << a << endl;
```

output is expected 1.2345678

If I type

```
cout << setprecision(4) << a << endl;
```

output is expected 1.234

If I type

```
cout << setprecision(12) << a << endl;
```

output is expected 1.23456789000 or 1.23456789472 where "...472" is trash

Comment: Please add details. What is the expected output? What does your `<<` actually put into the stream?

Comment: It is transparent to you, every float would be displayed with given precision (unless you use manipulator yourself)

Answer (score 0):

You can read the stream precision with [`std::ios_base::precision`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/precision). So in your streaming overload, you could do something like:

```
ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const MyClass& myobject){
    const auto precision = os.precision();
    // Print our big number knowing the total precision. 
}
```

In an example like:

```
cout << setprecision(4) << a << endl;
```

The stream from the [return value of `std::setprecision`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/setprecision) will be the altered stream which now has the new value for `precision`. Using `precision()` gives you this value, so you should be good from here.